# OpenGL / FreeType font text not showing on window

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, freetype

I am trying to render text on OpenGL with FreeType library but I'm struggling to get it working. I tried following the tutorial on learnopengl.com but I can't follow the shaders exactly as they are using GLSL version 3.3 and mine is 1.2. I somehow manage to make my own shader function and there are no errors so what's the problem?

Here's my code:

```
void setShaders() {
//Read our shaders into the appropriate buffers
const char *vertexSource = "text.vs";
const char *fragmentSource = "text.fs";
std::ifstream vShaderFile;
std::ifstream fShaderFile;
std::string vertexCode;
std::string fragmentCode;

vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

//Open files
vShaderFile.open(vertexSource);
fShaderFile.open(fragmentSource);
std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
//Read file's buffer contents into streams
vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

//Convert stream into string
vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();

vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

const GLchar *source = (const GLchar *) vertexCode.c_str();
glShaderSourceARB(vertexShader, 1, &source, 0);
glCompileShaderARB(vertexShader);

GLint isCompiled = 0;
glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);

source = (const GLchar *) fragmentCode.c_str();
glShaderSourceARB(fragmentShader, 1, &source, 0);
glCompileShaderARB(fragmentShader);

isCompiled = 0;
glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);

program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(program);

GLint isLinked = 0;
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &isLinked);
if (isLinked == GL_FALSE) {
    GLint maxLength = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

    std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(maxLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, maxLength, &maxLength, &infoLog[0]);

    glDeleteProgram(program);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    
    return;
} else {
    glUseProgram(program);
    GLfloat matrix[16];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "coord"), 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
}
```

}

RenderText()

```
void RenderText(std::string text, float x, float y, float scale, glm::vec3 color) {
// activate corresponding render state
setShaders();
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "textColor"), color.x, color.y, color.z);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// iterate through all characters
std::string::const_iterator c;
for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++) {
    Character ch = Characters[*c];

    float xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
    float ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

    float w = ch.Size.x * scale;
    float h = ch.Size.y * scale;
    // update VBO for each character
    float vertices[6][4] = {
            {xpos,     ypos + h, 0.0f, 0.0f},
            {xpos,     ypos,     0.0f, 1.0f},
            {xpos + w, ypos,     1.0f, 1.0f},

            {xpos,     ypos + h, 0.0f, 0.0f},
            {xpos + w, ypos,     1.0f, 1.0f},
            {xpos + w, ypos + h, 1.0f, 0.0f}
    };
    // render glyph texture over quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
    // update content of VBO memory
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // render quad
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    // now advance cursors for next glyph (note that advance is number of 1/64 pixels)
    x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale; // bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (2^6 = 64)
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

main()

```
int main() {
// glfw: initialize and configure
// ------------------------------
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// glfw window creation
// --------------------
GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
if (!window) {
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);/**/

// OpenGL state
// --------------------
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;
err = FT_New_Face(ft, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-RI.ttf", 0, &face);
if (err != 0) {
    printf("Failed to load face\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // disable byte-alignment restriction

for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

    // load character glyph
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }
    // generate texture
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
    );
    // set texture options
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // now store character for later use
    Character character = {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            static_cast<unsigned int>(face->glyph->advance.x)
    };
    Characters.insert(std::pair<char, Character>(c, character));
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

// destroy FreeType once we're finished
FT_Done_Face(face);
FT_Done_FreeType(ft);

// configure VAO/VBO for texture quads
// -----------------------------------
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    // input
    // -----
    processInput(window);

    // render
    // ------
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat black[4] = {0,0,0,1};
    glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program,"color"),1,black);

    RenderText("This is sample text", 25.0f, 25.0f, 1.0f, glm::vec3(0.5, 0.8f, 0.2f));
    RenderText("(C) LearnOpenGL.com", 540.0f, 570.0f, 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.3, 0.7f, 0.9f));

    // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

This is my text.vs

```
#version 120

attribute vec4 coord;
varying vec2 texcoord;

void main(void) {
gl_Position = vec4(coord.xy, 0, 1);
texcoord = coord.zw;
}
```

and my text.fs

```
#version 120 
void main() {
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);}
```

I've tried many solutions on Google but I'm still getting a blank window... Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: I would check the coordinates first. Remove the matrix multiplication and just draw the text using OpenGL's native coordinate system, at for example 0,0 with a size of 0.1. Do you see anything? If so, then your matrices are wrong.

Comment: Is your vertex shader really written in one long line? GLSL spec says that there must be a line break after `#version XXX`.

Comment: @user253751 Hi, I have changed my matrix to coordinates code is above (text.vs). When you say matrix multiplication did you mean the one on text.vs? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @YakovGalka Hi, it's not written in one line, it's indented correctly now. Thanks.